# Sourcemap not mapping the correct line

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-2

I am using angular2-webpack-starter. I use VSCode and debbuger for chrome.
After hours trying to make debbuger working, I finally managed to have a breakpoint working, but it seems that it is not mapping the correct line. 
It is the same problem in Chrome Devtool as my breakpoint is in a TS file et mapping work with js files.

Any ideas to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, using `source-map` instead of `cheap-module-source-map` fixed my issue. (in webpack config)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2811